# Permission denied (publickey) on Amazon EC2

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, public-key

**Here is my problem.**

1. I created a new instance, use the same key pair of another instance.
2. SSH to the new instance, running ok.
3. I terminate the old instance.

And when I SSH to my new instance with the key, it got problem.

```
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-176-34-8-64.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [176.34.8.64]         port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file foobar.pem type -1
debug1: identity file foobar.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ec2-176-34-8-64.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/xudannie/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/xudannie/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: foobar.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

So I checked other answers, maybe I should create a new instance and mount this one to add public keys. Is this the only way to solve the problem?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please note that instances are independent of each other. If you are implying that new instance got corrupted because you killed older one. It's probably a wrong direction to think of.

Comment: Thanks, I mean the way provided here[http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-fix-ebs-root](http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-fix-ebs-root). Maybe I create a new one and setup the environment will be more quickly.

Comment: Yeah, just fireup a new instance. Looks like you lost access to this one anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you got it sorted or not but permissions on your private key may give that error without any further specification. I´m aware that you in this specific case probably didn´t change the file permissions though.

However, if thats the case, just `sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/your_private_key`
Especially putty in windows enviroments seems to just deny access, linux usually tells you to change the permission.